# Get telegram group ID

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

At first i should emphasis that this is a question about telegram GROUP NOT CHANNEL.I need to get group id to send message via telgram api.
I have review [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414021/get-telegram-channel-group-id) .
using *@rawDataBot* needs to add bot to group, that is not possible most of the times. *CuteGram* does not login (does not send login code) .so i can say none of the proposed method works.

so is there a new method -except adding a bot to the group- to get telgram group ID ?

if the answer is no, i need to know if it is possible to send message to group by using group name?!

Comment: It's not possible with Bot API without joining the group. You should instead use an mtproto client like telethon https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/ to get the dialogs in your telegram and match the group name, and then get the id.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to add [@chatBotRaw](https://t.me/RawDataBot) the bot will dump raw data, and you can copy their chat_id or anything else you need,

Remember to remove the bot afterwards because it dumps raw data of every message sent/received in the group.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way i found is

- open web-telegram in a browser
- right click on the group name on the left menu
- click 'inspect' button
- you will see the group id in the attribute **data-peer-id="-xxxxxxxxxx"** or **peer="-xxxxxxxxxx"**

Answer (score 0):

You can get chat id throw object "chat"
You can set middleware which handle new update
Example on Node.JS: bot.on('text', ctx => console.log('Chat id is:', ctx.chat.id))
P.S. group id and chat id are same

Answer (score 0):

if using a bot is acceptable, you can use @username_to_id_bot - no need to add it to a group, just send username or invite link and get the id